# Android how to make animated setSelection() for listfragment?

Tags: android, listview, animation, fragment

How is it possible to make a smooth setSelection(position) for listFragment. For regular listviews it is possible to call smoothScrollToPosition(position) but this only works for api lvl 8 and above but this doesn't matter because it doesn't work for listfragment and not down to api lvl 7.

Any ideas, suggestions that will help implement this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mark D is correct that, if you want to smooth scroll the `ListView` in a `ListFragment`, you need to call `getListView()` on the `ListFragment` and then call `smoothScrollToPosition(int)` on the `ListView` that is returned. Of course, this only works down to API level 8 because that is when `smoothScrollToPosition(int)` was introduced to `AbsListView`, the superclass of `ListView`.

I suppose you could look at the code in `AbsListView.java` to see what it does and try to replicate it in your own subclass of `AbsListView` or `ListView`. It's immediately clear that `smoothScrollToPosition(pos)` just calls `start(pos)` on an instance of an inner class `PositionScroller`, but it looks somewhat complicated to replicate that behavior in your own subclass since the `PositionScroller` gets called from a several other spots like `onDetachedFromWindow()`, `public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus)`. It's not at all clear to me how you would cleanly integrate your PositionScroller behavior into your subclass based on the API 7 version of `AbsListView`.

If it were my decision, with API 7 and earlier making up less than 8% of devices accessing the Android Market in the latest [data set](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html), I'd just punt and do something simpler like `setSelectionFromTop` whenever the API is lower than 8 (detected by Build.VERSION.SDK_INT).

Comment: Thanks for a throughly answer :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can do this for API level 7, but see if you can't smooth scroll by going like this:

```
listFragment.getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: have you actually tryed it? This is not supported for listfragment.

Comment: I was able to get a version of this to work on Honeycomb device and an ICS device.  Where do you see that it is unsupported (you may be right)?